# bxslider How is it possible to make thumbnails like a carousel?

Tags: slideshow, carousel, bxslider

I use this slider http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1.
It works, but I have a lots of elements and thumbnails don't fit on one line and move to the next line. How is it possible to do thumbnails like a carousel? 
I'll be very grateful to you for help.
Regards.

My code is here [http://jsfiddle.net/dmeX5/]

Answer (score 16):

There is an open issue for this bxslider's Github. For the moment you can use the code provided [here](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/issues/274).

The code below produces [this](http://gualini.adostudio.it/realizations_2.html#).

```
    /*............ slider realizzazioni (BIG) */

        var realSlider= $j("#sliderBigReal ul").bxSlider({
            speed:1000,
            pager:false,
            nextText:'',
            prevText:'',
            infiniteLoop:false,
            hideControlOnEnd:true,
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);

            }

        });

        var realThumbSlider=$j("#sliderThumbReal ul").bxSlider({
          minSlides: 4,
          maxSlides: 4,
          slideWidth: 156,
          slideMargin: 12,
          moveSlides: 1,
          pager:false,
          speed:1000,
          infiniteLoop:false,
          hideControlOnEnd:true,
          nextText:'<span></span>',
            prevText:'<span></span>',
            onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
                /*$j("#sliderThumbReal ul .active").removeClass("active");
                $slideElement.addClass("active"); */

            }
        });

        linkRealSliders(realSlider,realThumbSlider);

        if($j("#sliderThumbReal li").length<5){
            $j("#sliderThumbReal .bx-next").hide();
        }




// sincronizza sliders realizzazioni
function linkRealSliders(bigS,thumbS){

    $j("#sliderThumbReal ul").on("click","a",function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var newIndex=$j(this).parent().attr("slideIndex");
        bigS.goToSlide(newIndex);
    });



}

//slider!=$thumbSlider. slider is the realslider
function changeRealThumb(slider,newIndex){

    var $thumbS=$j("#sliderThumbReal");
    $thumbS.find('.active').removeClass("active");
    $thumbS.find('li[slideIndex="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass("active");

    if(slider.getSlideCount()-newIndex>=4)slider.goToSlide(newIndex);
    else slider.goToSlide(slider.getSlideCount()-4);

}
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer above is correct, but there was a typo, it had slideIndex when we are using data-slideIndex or data-slide-index on bxslider4.

Here is a jsfiddle with it working perfectly:
http://jsfiddle.net/DcpdT/25/

```js
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

var realSlider= $j("ul#bxslider").bxSlider({
      speed:1000,
      pager:false,
      nextText:'',
      prevText:'',
      infiniteLoop:false,
      hideControlOnEnd:true,
      onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        changeRealThumb(realThumbSlider,newIndex);
        
      }
      
    });
    
    var realThumbSlider=$j("ul#bxslider-pager").bxSlider({
      minSlides: 4,
      maxSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 156,
      slideMargin: 12,
      moveSlides: 1,
      pager:false,
      speed:1000,
      infiniteLoop:false,
      hideControlOnEnd:true,
      nextText:'<span></span>',
      prevText:'<span></span>',
      onSlideBefore:function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
        /*$j("#sliderThumbReal ul .active").removeClass("active");
        $slideElement.addClass("active"); */

      }
    });
    
    linkRealSliders(realSlider,realThumbSlider);
    
    if($j("#bxslider-pager li").length<5){
      $j("#bxslider-pager .bx-next").hide();
    }

// sincronizza sliders realizzazioni
function linkRealSliders(bigS,thumbS){
  
  $j("ul#bxslider-pager").on("click","a",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var newIndex=$j(this).parent().attr("data-slideIndex");
        bigS.goToSlide(newIndex);
  });
}

//slider!=$thumbSlider. slider is the realslider
function changeRealThumb(slider,newIndex){
  
  var $thumbS=$j("#bxslider-pager");
  $thumbS.find('.active').removeClass("active");
  $thumbS.find('li[data-slideIndex="'+newIndex+'"]').addClass("active");
  
  if(slider.getSlideCount()-newIndex>=4)slider.goToSlide(newIndex);
  else slider.goToSlide(slider.getSlideCount()-4);

}
```

```html
    <!-- The main images -->
    <ul id="bxslider">
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/ff0099.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/ff0000.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff000.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The thumbnails -->
    <ul id="bxslider-pager">
<li data-slideIndex="0"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png"></a></li>
<li data-slideIndex="1"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ff0099.png"></a></li>
<li data-slideIndex="2"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/ff0000.png"></a></li>
<li data-slideIndex="3"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff000.png"></a></li>
    <li data-slideIndex="4"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png"></a></li>
    <li data-slideIndex="5"><a href=""><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.png"></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: pls fix the jsfiddle too. i got a headache until i realized the typo was in there too.